# How to ensure only 1 collapse works at a time?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following code where pressing my text in the `li` will open an image to the right and cause a text below it to show. Currently if I press 2 `li`, both texts under it will show. However, I only want to open 1 text below it at a time. How can I do this without any javascript and only using collapse or bootstrap classes?

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 my-auto text-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#offer">
       <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#offerText" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Offer</h3></a>
       <h5 id="offerText" class="collapse font-weight-normal my-4">Sample offer</h5>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#find">
      <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#findText">Find</h3></a>
      <h5 id="findText" class="collapse font-weight-normal my-4">Sample find</h5>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#submit">
      <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submitText">Submit</h3></a>
      <h5 id="submitText" class="collapse font-weight-normal my-4">To submit</h5>
    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#getPaid">
      <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#paidText">Get paid</h3></a>
      <h5 id="paidText" class="collapse font-weight-normal my-4">Sample paid</h5>
    </li>
  </ul>                
</div>

<div class="tab-content col-12 col-md-6 my-auto">
  <div id="offer" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="col-md-6 my-auto">
      <img class="d-none d-lg-block img-small" src="assets/images/offer.svg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="find" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="col-md-6 my-auto">
      <img class="d-none d-lg-block img-small" src="assets/images/find.svg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="submit" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="col-md-6 my-auto">
      <img class="d-none d-lg-block img-small" src="assets/images/submit.svg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="getPaid" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="col-md-6 my-auto">
      <img class="d-none d-lg-block img-small" src="assets/images/get-paid.svg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-parent` on the `collapse` containers to achieve accordeon functionality.

**Changes** in your `<ul />`:

- add an ID
- set `aria-expanded` to `false` on your first item
- set `data-parent` to your ID on the `.collapse` containers

**HTML**

```
<ul id="my-parent">
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#offer">
            <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#offerText" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">Offer</h3>
        </a>
        <h5 id="offerText" class="collapse font-weight-normal my-4" data-parent="#my-parent">Sample offer</h5>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#find">
            <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#findText">Find</h3>
        </a>
        <h5 id="findText" class="collapse font-weight-normal my-4" data-parent="#my-parent">Sample find</h5>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#submit">
            <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submitText">Submit</h3>
        </a>
        <h5 id="submitText" class="collapse font-weight-normal my-4" data-parent="#my-parent">To submit</h5>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#getPaid">
            <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#paidText">Get paid</h3>
        </a>
        <h5 id="paidText" class="collapse font-weight-normal my-4" data-parent="#my-parent">Sample paid</h5>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/ko9neruw/)**
**[DOCUMENTATION](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accessibility)**